# make new row and insert maximum value of multi calculation

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to make a code to help my investment. What I wanna do is to find a company's Excess Cash

my DataFrame is like this :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[2304009, 268860, 818937], index=['sales', 'cash', 'financial instument'], columns=['target'])
```

The formula for 'Excess Cash' is like this :

```
max(0, 'cash' + 'financial instument' - 'sales'*0.2)
```

What I could do so far with all my super power was :

```
df.loc['Excess Cash'] = df.loc['cash'] + df.loc['financial instument'] - df.loc['sales']*0.2
```

but I can't do the max(0, the number i've got) and put this number in the row 'Excess Cash'

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`numpy.maximum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html) for max value of one element `Series` and scalar:

```
s  = df.loc['cash'] + df.loc['financial instument'] - df.loc['sales']*0.2
df.loc['Excess Cash'] = np.maximum(0, s)
```

You can test it with another value, like:

```
s  = df.loc['cash'] + df.loc['financial instument'] - df.loc['sales']*0.2
df.loc['Excess Cash'] = np.maximum(1000000, s)
print (df)
                        target
sales                2304009.0
cash                  268860.0
financial instument   818937.0
Excess Cash          1000000.0
```